# With iptables, is it possible to route only certain domains?

Tags: iptables, openvpn, ip-forwarding, policy-routing, tailscale

I'm routing specific devices through a separate gateway device that connects to a Tailscale VPN exit node.

I'm using this command so my device can act as NAT router to Tailscale:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tailscale0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But this only works because I've enabled IP forwarding in sysctl:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

I'd like to be more specific with my NAT routing such that only traffic to certain domains go through the `tailscale0` interface and everything else passes through. I'm assuming this is the same issue you'd see with OpenVPN's `tun0` and `tap0` interfaces.

How can I accomplish L3 domain routing with `iptables`?

Comment: How would you know whether a specific IP address "belongs" to a domain? Have you ever tried to think this through?

Comment: As far as I understand, `iptables` allows mapping domains, so this is definitely possible. Another option is `route`, but I'm pretty sure this can be done with `iptables`.

Comment: The iptables *command* will resolve a DNS name into an IP address and send the resulting IP address along the rule to the kernel. From now on, it's all about IP addresses. Same with routing.

Comment: Yeah. There also is the little problem that ip packets may belong to multiple domains - how would that work? No, IP tables works only on IP addresses.